# How to share a PHP code across multiple websites/servers?

Tags: php, linux, git, web-deployment

I have many PHP websites that are in different servers (LAMP servers in the cloud). They are different websites from different clients, but I use some common code in all of them. All this common code I put in a Common_Code_Folder, that I use as a library with classes, controllers, functions, etc.

The structure is like this:

```
Server 1
> Common_Code_Folder
> Root_Folder
    > Code Website 1

Server 2
> Common_Code_Folder
> Root_Folder
    > Code Website 2

Server 3
> Common_Code_Folder
> Root_Folder
    > Code Website 3
```

Etc ...

I am looking for a smarter solution for deploying this when I change anything in the Common_Code folder.

What I do right now:

When I change any file inside the Common_Code folder, I need to connect in FTP for all the websites, and upload the common_code folder for all of them. If I have 15 websites, I need to do it 15 times!

Is there a way to automatize that? Maybe GIT? Maybe a deployment code?

Comment: Sure, a typical scenario _is_ using `git` or any other version control system. You simply pull from the repository which can be done automatically, maybe `cron` based, or by some administration call.

Comment: @arkascha is on the right track. Use git submodules : http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2014/git-submodules-for-dependent-or-common-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To synchronize your code I recommend:

- put your code in `Common_Code_Folder` into a GIT repository.
- use a script to deploy new versions pull new code (`git pull`)
- this script can be executed manually on demand or by cron

If your code has access to a database, the script (e.g. a PHP script) should also

- check for database changes
- apply database migrations

Then your auto deploy process runs safely even if the database changes.

Since this common code is kind of a library to your custom PHP code, you also can update it via [composer](https://getcomposer.org/). Then your common code gets installed in the directory `vendor`. This is a common practice, e.g. in [Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html) framework.

Comment: Thanks. I am using GIT and it is working. I just need to commit and push the changes, and my servers (Jelastic) pulls all the updates.